# Understanding ST L3GD20 Gyro datasheet's cut-off value

Tags: gyro

Table 21 on page 32 of the [L3GD20 datasheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00036465.pdf) has a column named cut-off:

[image: Table 21 (Complete)]

The data sheet doesn't explain what this is, and it doesn't even have a unit. Does anyone what it means?

Answer (score 1):

It's the cutoff frequency of the digital low-pass filter, in Hz. It's controlled by the `BW` bits in the control register, but it's also affected by the output sample rate (or `ODR`), which is set by the `DR` bits.